# $2$ problems from Dispersive PDEs

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I have to problems to solve and I am looking for a good lecture for it:

1. We have $f\in\mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ i.e. $f$ is of Schwarz class. Show that for any $s>\frac{n}{2}$, $||f||_{L^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^n)}\le C(s,n) ||<\nabla>^s f||_{L^2(\mathbb{R}^n)}$, where $<\nabla>=(1+|x|^2)^{\frac{1}{2}}$.
2. If $f\in L^1_{loc}(\mathbb{R}^n,E^*)$ is such that $\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}f(x)[\phi(x)]\,dx=0$ for every test function $\phi\in\mathcal{C}^{\infty}_c(\mathbb{R}^n,E)$, then $f(x)=0$ for a.e. $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$.

I know that second question is similar to Fundamental lemma of calculus of variations but I don't know how to connect it. Do you know books when I could find some help to this excerises?

Comment: It seems like s should appear in at least one more place in 1. #2 is just density: write f as a sum of countably many $L^1$ functions with disjoint supports, then use density of $L^2$ in $L^1$ followed by density of $C^\infty_c$ in $L^2$. You get that each of the localized functions has zero $L^2$ norm.

Comment: Honestly, I don't understand. Could You be more specific?